# Estimote SDK calculate distance in UTIL function

Tags: android, estimote

I currently having a project on calculating distance using Bluetooth signal.

Below the code i got from Estimote SDK util. I am wondering what is "D" imply in this code and what is the reason then rssi equal to 0 will return -1.0D.

```
private static double computeAccuracy(int rssi, int measuredPower) {
    if(rssi == 0) {
        return -1.0D;
    } else {
        double ratio = (double)rssi / (double)measuredPower;
        double rssiCorrection = 0.96D + Math.pow((double)Math.abs(rssi), 3.0D) % 10.0D / 150.0D;
        return ratio <= 1.0D?Math.pow(ratio, 9.98D) * rssiCorrection:(0.103D + 0.89978D * Math.pow(ratio, 7.71D)) * rssiCorrection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your code or where did you get it from?

Comment: this code is from Estimote SDK util as i mentioned .

Answer (score 1):

"D" refers to double value. And check this - https://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/Utils.html. "-1" is returned when there is no compute accuracy to be calculated.

Comment: Thank you so much bro. . this really help alot